# Visual Studio Error - FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, f#, visual-studio-2017

I have encountered a very iritating problem using Visual Studio 2017 Community. When downloading any package from NPM (here for example System.Web.Http.Common) every time I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

My project does not have any Fsharp files, it is pure ASP.NET project.

Update of VS did not help.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: `npm`? you mean `nuget` I assume.

Comment: yes, exactly, nuget package manager

Comment: Does this happen with a fresh console project or on a specific project?